# Sap UI 5 css on button

Tags: button, sapui5

I was just trying to implement CSS on Button. but it is not working.

```
<core:View controllerName="sap.hcm.Address" xmlns="sap.ui.commons" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <html:style>
      .mySuperRedButton {
         color: red;
      }
   </html:style>
   <Panel>
      <Button class="mySuperRedButton" text="Press Me!"/>
   </Panel>
<core:View>
```

Reference link: http://www.spyvee.com/SAPHTML5_DemoKit/docs/guide/MVC.html

Answer (score 0):

The button consists of multiple HTML/DOM Elements. There might be styles applied on some of those inner control elements as well. This is exactly what happened in your case:

```
.sapMBtnInner {
  color: #333333;
}
```

overrides your CSS. You can overcome this by either using !important (the less-preferable way):

```
.mySuperRedButton {
  color: red !important;
}
```

or by referencing the inner class:

```
.mySuperRedButton .sapMBtnInner {
  color: red;
}
```

If you are more interested in the inner HTML of a Control you can either check the DOM or the controls renderer class.

Btw: You should include your CSS as a separate file for better reuse and a cleaner project structure.

BR
Chris